# C++ Multiplying Matrices of different sizes

Tags: c++, matrix-multiplication

I have an error checker already to be sure the columns of the first matrix == rows of the second matrix, so I know they can be multiplied, but I can't figure out how to work it so that I can multiply matrices of various sizes, like [3x2] * [2x5]. Here's what I have:

```
Matrix Matrix::MultMatrices(Matrix A, bool& error){
if(error){
    cout <<"Unable to multiply these matrices";
    cout <<endl;
}

//Set dimensions for product matrix
int nRows=this->getRows();
int nCols=A.getCols();

Matrix prod(nRows, nCols);
int product;

//first two loops navigate prod Matrix for placement of answers
for(int i=0; i<nRows; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<nCols; j++){


        prod.setElement(i, j, product);
    }
}

return prod;
}
```

If I had another two loops I could find the product and *setElement* each time through the loop...would that work?

Comment: Why does it "work" if you pass a 2x2 and 3x3 matrix?

Comment: That would work, but what makes you question that? Do you understand the algorithm you are trying to implement? Maybe you should just try and see?

Comment: @Andrey no, he don't understand the algorithm. Have you noticed he only uses two nested loops? Matrix product needs three

Answer (score 0):

First, it's your responsibility to set error:

```
int commonSize = getCols();
if( A.getRows() != commonSize ) {
    error = true;
    return *this;
}
error = false;
```

Second, there's a missing inner loop there:

```
for(int i=0; i<nRows; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<nCols; j++){
        int product = 0;
        for(int k=0; k<commonSize; k++){
            product += getElement(i, k) * A.getElement(k, j);
        }
        prod.setElement(i, j, product);
    }
}
```